# Problems with appcache

Tags: php, html, html5-appcache

I am having some issues with the browsers caching my files. Chrome works just fine but both IE and FireFox don't cache the page.

IE gives me an error saying the current page doesn't exist on the server (which it obviously does). Then it gives me an Appcache Fatal error.

Firefox doesn't give me any errors, it just doesn't cache the file.

I am using SSL and apache. Here is my appcache

```
CACHE MANIFEST

CACHE
/fhr/background.jpg
/fhr/logo.png
/fhr/index.php

#v0.1
```

And here is the HTML file (it does have some PHP before the  tag if that makes a difference)

```
<html manifest="index.appcache">
```

Comment: Are you returning the manifest with the content-type `text/cache-manifest`?